# Alembic is not detecting difference between database and code

Tags: python-3.x, alembic

I delete the contents of the alembic_version table in my database, and I then delete the contents of the alembic/versions directory.

I then run:

```
PYTHONPATH=. alembic -c ./alembic.ini revision --autogenerate -m 'your message about the migration'
```

and

```
alembic upgrade head
```

but despite the code and the database not matching, alembic seems to do nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from alembic import context
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config, pool
from logging.config import fileConfig

# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
from serve_spec_guru.db_global import db_unikernelguru
from serve_spec_guru.model_documents import Documents
from serve_spec_guru.model_filesets import Filesets
from serve_spec_guru.model_hosts import Hosts
from serve_spec_guru.model_issues import Issues
from serve_spec_guru.model_messages import Messages
from serve_spec_guru.model_payments import Payments
from serve_spec_guru.model_unikernels import Unikernels
from serve_spec_guru.model_websites import Websites
from serve_spec_users.model_users import Users

target_metadata = db_guru.Base.metadata


# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline():
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url, target_metadata=target_metadata, literal_binds=True)

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix='sqlalchemy.',
        poolclass=pool.NullPool)

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=target_metadata
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()

if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

Comment: I'm not expert with alembic but I saw this unanswered. What is in your `alembic.ini` in the `[alembic]` section? What is the output of your `alembic revision`? I have had maybe the same thing happen when alembic is looking at my test database which has all the tables already. Are you sure the database alembic is looking at doesn't have all the tables already?